# Django filtering QueryString by MultiSelectField values?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using [MultiSelectField](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) to store a topic/topic's of conversation

My model looks somewhat like this:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    (...)
    note= models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    TOPIC_CHOICES =(
        (1,"about cats"),
        (2, "about dogs"),
        (3, "about fluffy little things"),
    )
    topic =MultiSelectField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES)
```

I'm using `ListView` and filtering by GET parameters inside `get_queryset`:

form extract:

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    (...)
    topic = MultipleChoiceField(choices=Conversation.TOPIC_CHOICES, required=False)
```

get_queryset extract :

```
(...)
if form.cleaned_data['topic']:
                search_params.update({'topic__in': form.cleaned_data['topic']})
(...)
return qs.filter(**search_params)
```

This method worked fine for single value choice fields.

But in this case if I for ex. select in form "about cats" I got only objects that topic is set to cats **only**("about cats" and nothing else -single value).

What I want is all objects in which one of topic values is 1-"about cats". This mean if some object have topic=`1,3`(cats and fluffy things) it should appear too

Second scenario: I select "about cats" and "about dogs" in form - I want **all** objects that have cats as one of the topic's **and all** objects that have a dogs as one of the topic's
Right now when I select more than one option for ex. cats and dogs I get all that have **only** cats and all that got **only** dogs as a topic

Is there any other field lookup string instead of `__in` that will achieve that?
If not what is most hassle free way to do that?

Comment: How does the form.cleaned_data['topic'] return? Is it a list of strings or just a string?

Comment: `logger.debug(form.cleaned_data[topic])`
prints out : DEBUG [u'1', u'2'] so it's a list
PS Look at my latest edit - I made a false statement in the beginning and corrected it now.

Comment: Try: if form.cleaned_data['topic']:
                search_params.update({'topic__in': map(int, form.cleaned_data['topic'])})

Answer (score 5):

How about using Django Q sets for this, so your filter would look like:

```
...objects.filter( Q(topic__exact = cat) | Q(topic__startswith = '%s,' % cat) | Q(topic__endswith = ',%s' % cat) | Q(topic__contains = ',%s,' % cat),
other_attributes = 'xxx',
```

Answer (score 3):

[MultiSelectField](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) stores vales as a comma separated string in a CharField, so you basically want `.topic__contains=topic` instead of  `.topic__in=topic`

However, depending on your search form, you'll want to join the conditions using different boolean operators to either narrow or widen the results. Depending on your needs, I would do one of the following:

- Use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to build a complex query using `OR` joins (more complex, but more versatile)
- Unpack named parameters from a dict into a `.filter()` (simpler, but constraining)

## Dynamically build the query with Q.

This is the better method. It lets you use `OR`, `AND`, `NOT` or `XOR` in the query to refine search options.

```py
# ...
search_params = Q()

# Let's say we have other search parameters also
search_params = search_params | Q(note__contains="example note")

if form.cleaned_data['topic']:
    search_params = search_params | Q(topic__in=form.cleaned_data['topic'])

# ...
return qs.filter(search_params)
```

The resulting MYSQL query will look something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `search_form`
    WHERE (
        `note` LIKE '%example note%' OR
        `topic` LIKE '%about cats%'
    )
```

## Unpack named parameters from a dict

This method can only be used to narrow the search results using `AND` in the query.

```py
# ...

search_params = {}

# let's say there are other items in the query
search_params['note__contains'] = 'example note'

if form.cleaned_data['topic']:
    search_params['topic__contains'] = form.cleaned_data['topic']

# ...
# unpack the search_params into the named parameters
return qs.filter(**search_params)
```

This will effectively build the Django query something like:

```py
SearchForm.objects.filter(
    note__contains="example note",
    topic__contains="about cats"
)
```

The resulting database query will be something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `search_form`
    WHERE (
        `note` LIKE '%example note%' AND 
        `topic` LIKE '%about cats%'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

[MultiSelectField](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) is basically a CharField that stores the multiple choices values as a comma separated string.

Therefore you need a full table scan to perform this kind of QuerySet filtering on a MultiSelectField. You can use [__regex field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) to filter your QuerySet to match a given choice value:

```
(...)
searched_topics = form.cleaned_data['topic']
if searched_topics:
    search_topic_regexp = "(^|,)%s(,|$)" % "|".join(searched_topics)
    search_params.update({'topic__regex': search_topic_regexp})
(...)
```

For better performances (to avoid the full table scan on the topic field when you have a lot of Conversation entries), you should not use MultiSelectField but a [ManyToMany relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) (that would use a separated join table).

Comment: Does m2m approach will have any impact in case i only will be using it to 1-filter 2- sort ? This will always check topics of all enteries in question.

Comment: Yes, because your database should use an index to filter the Conversation entries based on their related topics. The performance of this SQL request (and the difference with the MultiSelectField approach) depends on the total number of Conversation entries and on the number of entries returned.

Comment: So if i add a model "topic" with one field named "name" it will work faster even if then it need to search two tables instead of one? Sorry for keeping asking stupid questions but im trying to understand...

Comment: It will be faster "most of the time" (when you have enough Conversation entries and when the number of Conversations that match the requested topic is not too big)

Comment: I will rather stick to MultiChoice field because no. of topics in system is rather small- 3 as for this time- and no. of conversations will be rather huge so number of conversations  per topic will be big. Is there a way to adapt this answer to work with multiple topics? I mean `for each topic in form.cleaned_data['topic']` append OR topic to search_choice_regxp - I cant figure out how to format  the expression to make it possible to append next topic to the end of string.

Comment: You can use | in your regex to match multiple values. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I know about "|" but i dont know how to format this regex to work with any number of topics. waiting for edit. Thanks